# Empty object error, is there a way to work around this?

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I use STL priority queue:

```
priority_queue <Vertex, vector<pair<Vertex, Path*>>, PathComparator>
```

> - left of '.identifier' must have class/struct/union

In `PathComparator` class I have a function overload operator, but when I try to access the second Item of the pair I get the below error:

> Left of -> need identifier class struct

Is there a way to work around this? I need the second item to be pointer.

Comment: Please post some code.  Both the definition of the queue, and the lines that cause the error.

Comment: Gernot, it wont work